# Understanding Dangling References in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I am trying to educate myself as to how leaks or dangling references occurs in a garbage collected language like C#. I found a contrived example online which I modified and observed (via Task Manager) to be quiet "leaky" with every key stroke.

Source:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public class Something
    {
        int[] things;

        public Something() {
            things = new int[10000000];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < things.Length; ++i) {
                things[i] = rnd.Next();
            }
        }
    }

    static public class SomethingFactory
    {
        public static Something CreateSomething() {
            Something something = new Something();
            return something;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            while (true) {
                Console.ReadKey();

                Console.WriteLine("Creating...");
                Something s = SomethingFactory.CreateSomething();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Why does the dangling reference occur? At a glance, it seems the `Something s` is instantiated inside the scope of the `while (true)` and after the block ends, no other reference to the item should exist. Yet, with every key stroke I see a ~40mb increase in my application's memory usage that never seems to go down.

Comment: Are you running Debug code or with the debugger attached? Try running it without the debugger in Release mode.

Comment: in debug mode the scope of a variable is to the end of the function, therefore it doesn't get collected until the end of Main()

Comment: The garbage collector will collect your garbage when there is a need to clean up memory. Maybe because you have enough memory, it is not collected. You can more or less 'simulate' the garbage collector by replacing your `Console.ReadKey();` by  `if (Console.ReadLine == 'g') GC.Collect();`. During running your app, enter 'g' to set off the garbage collector. However, you should never do this in your code. The garbage collector is optimized to run when necessary. Doing it manually is bad practice. Try it for demo only.

Comment: I don't see any "leak" at all.  Remove the Console.ReadKey() call so you can see how this behaves long-term.

Comment: @mikez I was running a `Debug` build. Debugger or not it still performed the same however a `Release` build performed as expected. Memory jumped ~40mb the first time and stayed there. What is `Debug` doing differently?

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything out of the ordinary. A lot of the memory reported as in use can be reclaimed by the GC in your sample. However, keep in mind that when you observe the memory in task manager, you're looking at the process memory. In a managed app the CLR acts as a memory manager on behalf of your application. It allocates and frees memory at the process level.

The way that works is that it allocates chucks of memory to store objects on the managed heap. When the number of objects drop these chucks will eventually get released to the OS again. The thing to keep in mind is that the CLR tries to be clever about this, so it doesn't allocate and free every time the managed heap changes. Consequently, it is difficult to understand how the managed memory is used by looking at process level memory usage.

Most likely what you're seeing is that memory is allocated and not released because the CLR doesn't have any reason to free these chucks yet.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough the response. Conceptually this makes sense to me. What would motivate the CLR to finally release those chunks? Is it just when the system is running low? Also, see my comment above referencing @mikez's theory on why my app was behaving this way due to being a `Debug` build.

Comment: That would be implementation details. In my experience as long as there's no pressure on memory the CLR holds on to allocated memory, as releasing and re-allocating is inefficient. As Hans points out in his comment above, you need to monitor the system long-term to see how the CLR handles this.